# Google Analytic campaign tracking not showing up in report

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement Google Analytic campaign tracking in Android. I followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns

and here is what I've done:

Added this to AndroidManifest:

```
<!-- Used for install referral measurement-->
<service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService"/>
<receiver android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Followed this guide (https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns) to perform the broadcast:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.my.app/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es  "referrer" "utm_source%3Dtest_source%26utm_medium%3Dtest_medium%26utm_term%3Dtest_term%26utm_content%3Dtest_content%26utm_campaign%3Dtest_name"
```

I checked the logcat, it's showing this line correctly:

```
02-12 11:47:13.190: I/GAV3(18963): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source%3Dtest_source%26utm_medium%3Dtest_medium%26utm_term%3Dtest_term%26utm_content%3Dtest_content%26utm_campaign%3Dtest_name
```

However, it's having another 2 extra lines:

```
02-12 11:47:18.280: W/System.err(18963): [DEBUG] GbaRequest - GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
02-12 11:47:18.280: W/System.err(18963): [DEBUG] NafRequest - NafRequest: NafRequest constructor===useragent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
```

and I checked the GA report page under Acquisition-->Google Play-->Sources, and it's only showing (not set), (none) or (direct), but not the `source`, `medium`, etc I'm expecting to see: `test_source`, `test_medium`, etc.

- Note: I already changed the filter of the date to today's date, and have waited 24 hours, it's still not showing.

Anyone faces this and knows how to solve?

Comment: The System.err log entries are caused by someone calling System.err.println() from the code. This is definitely not the Google Analytics. It either a debug code that was left over in the app or bug in library you are linking in.

Answer (score 0):

The Campaign receiver and service have been moved to a different package name between v2 and v4 of Google Analytics SDK. This might be causing the problem.

In v2 the package is com.google.analytics.tracking.android:

```
com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver
com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService
```

In v4 the package is com.google.android.gms.analytics:

```
com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver
com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService
```

You should follow the dev guide from v4 instead of v2:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns