# Android Google analytics Campaign tracking not in Report

Tags: analytics, tracking

I really cant make this work tried hours. Android google analytics seems not a well discussed subject in stackoverflow yet. similar post(also no solution): 
[Google Analytic campaign tracking not showing up in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718957/google-analytic-campaign-tracking-not-showing-up-in-report)

i did everything exactly like described here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

also i get the message in adb Terminal: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign

But when i look into google analytics (http://www.google.com/intl/de/analytics/)

there is just no data arriving from my First installation of the APP.

please help, since this seems to be not covered at all nowhere...

Answer (score 0):

guess solved it, the google documentation is very bad.

what made my day is GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this); in the onStart(); class in the activity. which sends the whole campaign to the analytics report. it's not mentioned in the google manual.

excellent tutorial(still rare for google analytics):
http://benwilcock.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/working-with-google-analytics-api-v4-for-android/